# Need to place a Imageview below a EditText and a Button using LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I really need help getting an `Imageview` to sit below an `EditText` and `Button`. I really need this in a `LinearLayout`.
This is what I have so far, but the image doesn't show:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientaion="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/Button" 
         android:layout_weight="0"/>

     <EditText
         android:id="@id/edit_message"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/edit_message" 
         android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom" />
             <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/Android" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageView` was not visible because of the  `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_width` parameters as `fill_parent`,change it to `wrap_content` and put button1 and editText in on `LinearLayout` with `orientation` as horizontal and in main `LinearLayout` give orientation as vertical.

Try replacing your code with the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:src="@drawable/Android" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great. How does one make the image span to fill the rest of the area below the EditText and Button. From this, the image is sitting under the EditText in taking up most of the right corner Edit: I got it with scaleType. Thank you though, this worked perfectly

Comment: You want to fill the rest of space below editText and button with the image?Try my update code

Comment: Try my update code.If it worked then pls accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try dragging things in a layout and you can do it. Try this [image: the output will be like this]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/yourImage">
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/Button" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```